How to Connect Email System with Informix 4GL Database Using Shell Script for Automation?
I am using Shell Script for automation in an AiX environment, working with the Informix 4GL database. I have written an automation script that sends an email to the user. The user needs to reply to the email with "approve." Once the user replies with "approve," a file in my database needs to be moved to a different folder.
Is there any way to connect the mail system with the Informix database using Shell Script to achieve this functionality?
What I Was Expecting:
I was looking for a solution or guidance on:

How to set up a connection between the email system and the Informix database using shell scripting.

How to read and process email replies (e.g., checking for the word "approve").

How to trigger the database operation (moving the file) based on the email reply.



As a start: google for fetchmail and procmail.

You might want to correct the title and problem description.   You refer to "Informix 4gl database".  The database is called "Informix".  "Informix 4gl" is a programming language.
